# Jasper Reports Server 8.2 - How to get this to start on (Linux) OS boot?

Tags: jasperserver

Looking to get some help on getting Jasper Reports Server 8.2 community edition to start on boot on our Rocky Linux 9 install.

There isn't much documentation online, and the official documentation seems to be old or for a different flavor (?) of linux.

From the Jasper Reports Installation Guide for 8.2:
https://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/docs/js-jrs_8.2.0_install-guide.pdf

`Page 28: 2.6.2.2 Auto Start/Stop with Bundled Tomcat and PostgreSQL If you want JasperReports Server to start automatically when you reboot your Linux server, you need to install the JasperReports Server database and application server as services. If you have installed JasperReports Server using the binary installer with the bundled Tomcat and bundled PostgreSQL options, you'll find an example jasperserver service script in the following location: <js-install>/scripts/linux/jasperserver Edit this script and set permissions as described in the <js-install>/scripts/linux/readme file in the same location. Once installed, these services start automatically when you reboot, which also starts JasperReports Server.`

I have done this but returns this error:
service jasperserver does not support chkconfig

Upon following update from the website dated 2022:
https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/auto-startstop-bundled-tomcat-and-postgresql-linux
which says
`Resolution:

Try to add below 2 lines in the jasperserver script (both at /scripts/linux/jasperserver and /etc/init.d/jasperserver), save the file, and then try to run the command, sudo /sbin/chkconfig --add jasperserver and sudo /sbin/chkconfig jasperserver on

## chkconfig: 2 3 5

## description: some startup description`

I have edited 'jasperserver' service file available in the above link as necessary and as instructed, changed my PATH to match the path of the jasper studio install, as well as the user, root, which I used to install the software with.

The service now registers properly since I can now use

service jasperserver start/stop/restart

But 'chkconfig jasperserver on' still does not start the service on boot and shut the service down on shutdown/reboot.

Upon installing the file in /etc/init.d/ and changing permissions (chmod +x), on boot, the server will quickly turn on then off in a matter of seconds. I have observed this by spamming 'service jasperserver status' to observe the status of both tomcat and postgres.

What other options can I try?

Thank you very much and I hope the included information is sufficient.